# Open pwa app in react native with react native linking using parameters

Tags: javascript, react-native, progressive-web-apps

I have a problem, I need to open a pwa app through a link but I need to send it as a parameter as an ID so that the pwa app behaves differently depending on the ID, but I have no idea how to do that, can you help me? I'm using the expo SDK version 39 react-native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to Deep Linking, here is a snippet from the react native doc:  https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking

Handling Deep Links
There are two ways to handle URLs that open your app.

1. If the app is already open, the app is foregrounded and a Linking event is fired
   You can handle these events with Linking.addEventListener(url, callback).
2. If the app is not already open, it is opened and the url is passed in as the initialURL
   You can handle these events with Linking.getInitialURL(url) -- it returns a Promise that resolves to the url, if there is one.